# Service kids forks 20” wheel

Tags: suspension, children

The suspension forks on my kids bike are totally seized, never been great anyway, but I’d like to try to get them moving in some way.

First problem is how to disassemble. They are the standard fork sold on a decathlon wyldee and the sticker on the back says GST, rapid suspension technology.

My problem is they don’t have a bolt at the bottom of the lowers to undo and if I pop the top caps off there’s not much accessible there either.

Anyone had any experience servicing something like these? Any thoughts? Or just unserviceable?

Answer (score 1):

Most of these older design entry level fork have no serviceable parts the best you can do is disassembly it and cover all the moving parts in grease. On most this requires removal of the little plastic caps on the top. If you shine a flashlight in you will likely see a 5mm allen screw. To remove the screw you need a "LONG" allen wrench. Alternatively you can purchase a 3/8" drive 5mm socket and use a 3/8" drive socket extension to remove the screws. Count the number of turn it takes to remove the screw so they can be reinstalled in the same position.  Once the screws are removed the lowers will slide off. Clean everything on the lower inside and upper outsides. Examine the upper legs for rust and if necessary sand smooth and spray with epoxy paint. Cover everything with grease (I use white lithium) and reassemble. After all of this you may notice  little if any difference. Most of the forks I have seen on kids bikes are so stiff that children don't weigh enough to compress the fork anyway.

Comment: Thanks for that, I’ll give it another go!

Comment: Success! Managed to chain a bunch off Allen drill bit extenders! Did the job... now to clean an re assemble! Cheers!